# Accessing WCF REST service through IIS using CORS works locally but not from connected device

Tags: c#, wcf, iis, cors

I have a set of WCF services that I have enabled WebInvoke for.
One way that I want access them is through javascript on a simple webpage hosted by IIS.
In order to get this to work at all I had to enable CORS, which I managed using this guide:
http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/idof/2011/07/02/cross-origin-resource-sharing-cors-and-wcf/

However there is still an issue when I access the webpage across my local network from a different computer.

To give an example:

Two computers on the network Comp1 (10.0.0.1) and Comp2 (10.0.0.2).
Both IIS and WCF services are hosted by Comp1.

Using Firefox I can access the webpage from Comp1 using:
http:// 10.0.0.1:12345

This works as long as CORS is enabled according to the link above. If I disable CORS I get an error message saying that CORS is disabled.

If I use Firefox from Comp2 to access 10.0.0.1:12345 I get the same CORS error message no matter if I have the CORS code enabled in the WCF-server. The error message I get here is the same one as the one I get on Comp1 if CORS is disabled.

Does anyone have any suggestions on what might be wrong?

Everything (except js and html) is in C# using Visual Studio 2013.
Please tell me if I should include some code to get better help.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have custom header enabled for CORS support in IIS. If not add below settings to the root of web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
 <system.webServer>
   <httpProtocol>
     <customHeaders>
       <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
     </customHeaders>
   </httpProtocol>
 </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

More details for enabling cors on [server side](http://enable-cors.org/server.html) and [client side](http://enable-cors.org/client.html).

P.S. - You can also checkout [this](https://github.com/vendettamit/WebHttpBehaviorExtensions) new WCF rest behavior extension library that does support the CORS enabled behavior.

Comment: For some reason this code was not necessary for me.

Comment: I believe that it is already included in a different way through the guide I used for implementing CORS (see link in OP).

It turned out that my problem was mainly related to some confusion on my part as to how and when the javascript was executed and therefore some of the requests only worked on the hosting machine. It seems that it was not related to CORS at all, although that was the error message that I got.
Thanks all the same, your answer made me take a second look at some things in my code.